# Calculate resistance of coil/inductor made of PCB traces

Tags: resistance, trace, copper

This is to be a NFC coil/inductor of 1.1uH according do ST's eDesignSuite tool, with 7 turns.

[image]

The drawing above follows these parameters:

[image]

ST's tool give inductance value as 1.1uH, but also I need to know the resistance of entire track, in ohms.
I have measured the antenna total lenght on the layout software and it is 418 mm long.

So I have these parameters:

- 0.25mm width
- 418mm length
- 0.5 oz (17.5 micrometers) copper thickness

Then I entered these value of this calculator: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/trace-resistance-calculator/

And the result given by the site is 1.66 Ohms. Can I trust this value? I need the know correct value of resistance to calculate the components of RF portion of NFC filter and matching circuits.

The board will have 0.5 oz copper thickness, I can guarantee this.

Help please. Regards.

Comment: Try another calculator or do a hand calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resistivity of Annealed copper:  1.72x10-8 Ωm

Resistivity is defined as:

\$ \rho = R\cdot \frac{A}{l}\$

therefore \$ R = \frac{\rho \cdot l}{A} \$

your length is 0.418m your area is \$0.25\,\mathrm{mm}\times 17.5\,\mu \mathrm{m}\$

therefore your resistance = \$ \frac{ 1.72\times10^{-8} \,\Omega \mathrm{m} \,\times\, 0.418\, \mathrm{m}}{ 0.25\,\mathrm{mm} \,\times\, 17.5\,\mu \mathrm{m}} = 1.64\,\Omega\$ at 20C

Comment: 0.25m or 0.25mm?

Comment: 0.25m, as in 0.25e-3.  I prefer to keep everything in base-SI ... stops errors. I have added units to clarfy

Comment: As Neil_UK states you must consider the skin effect which will increase the resistance considerably compared to the measured DC resistance.

Comment: @jakobHanslov the skin depth at 13.56MHz is 17.7um so that isn't a concern here when the copper thickness is 17.5um

Comment: Your units are still not in sync. Your comment says 0.25m but your answer and the original question say 0.25mm.

Answer (score 2):

You can trust the value of 1.66 ohms given by your calacuator, at DC, at 25 C, if the foil thinkness and etched width are as you've specified.

You would be surprised how much in error the etched width could be in practice.

The temperature variation is fairly small, +10% for 25 C change.

The main error will be if you want the resistance at NFC frequencies rather than DC, as the skin effect will increase it significantly.

Comment: skindepth shouldn't be a problem here since the copper weight thickness is > 2x the skindepth. However... the etching is since the controlled thickness and width isn't a precise art. I remember trying to use heavy copper as a "shunt resistor" ... took alot of per-card calibration to tweak out the variation

Comment: @JonRB By coincidence, copper skin depth at 13.5MHz is 17.7um. This means there will be some effective increase in resistivity, but maybe not as much as 'significantly'. Skindepth is not a problem when it's >> the actual copper thickness, and the thickness dominates the resistance. When copper thickness > skindepth, it's the latter that limits the resistance.

Comment: oh I agree, in this case due to the thickness of the copper in question, there shouldn't be a decrease in effective area.

Answer (score 1):

Standard copper foil is 0.000498 ohms per square of foil, for any size square!!!

Just to be very clear, this is 500 microOhms per square, whether 1 square micron or 10 square centimeterS. 
Notice this resistance is substantially lower than typical ESR values in capacitors. **BUT THE VALUE IS NOT ZERO**

This fact is useful for copper resistor design, or for examining hot spots where current crowds, etc.

===================

This value is for 1 ounce of copper per square foot, which is the 1.4 mil thickness or 35 microns.

And 35 microns used in skin_depth formula will produce 1 neper attenuation to penetrating waves at about 4MHz.

Or 10 nepers at 100X the frequency. Which is 88 dB.

The 88 dB attenuation is good explanation of why ground planes or power planes are so useful in creating clean systems, despite the presence of MCUs with 400MHz edge rates (1.25 nanosecond trise).

Comment: What thickness is 'standard' foil, 35um? 17um? Other? I like the nice round number of 500um/sq, I might even be able to remember that!

Answer (score 1):

You could not expect the width and the thickness of the track to be very precise.

There are tolerances depending on manufacture methods.

A track width of 250 µm may vary at least by +- 5 µm or more depending on fotoplotter resolution, resist exposure time, resist development time, under etching, etching time, etching temperature and a lot more.

Copper thickness of 18 µm may vary about +- 2 to 5 µm depending on manufacture.

So ask your PCB manufacturer about the tolerances for copper thickness and track width.