# NFC - design of inductor/"antenna" made of PCB traces

Tags: rf, pcb-design, inductor, coil, nfc

I did a layout of a NFC PCB inductor/"antenna"(I know it is not one exactly) drawn only on top side copper (nothing drawn on other layers at inductor area), and I wonder if there will be a considerable loss of working distance range on the opposite side due the PCB FR4 core itself is an obstacle... I need to read tags to both sides of the board at approximated distances.

I will share some screenshots.

Schematic of RF side, based on ST ST25R95, 230mW output power, QFN32:

[image]

Rant is 1.65 ohms and was calculated [HERE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/501516/calculate-resistance-of-coil-inductor-made-of-pcb-traces)

Lant is 1.09uH and came from ST's online tool eDesign Suite

[image]

This is my current drawing for the PCB coil/inductor. 10.5 x 26mm, 7 turns.

[image][image]

I wonder if I need (if it is suitable) to continue the "antenna" drawing on the bottom layer, and sum the inductances and resistances? (Or some other equation to calculate the inductance).

Also I wonder if I do that (antenna drawn on both sides) if I could reach more working distance (between the reader circuit and the tags) than doing coil only on top side.

If I need to continue the coil on bottom side also, do you have any recommendation about how to draw a good PCB inductor? So that I can reach the best distance range the chip can offer (it is 0.23W output power only, ST's ST25R95).

Regards.

***EDIT 1***

4 turns x 2 layer NFC coil.

TURN x mm:

1: 11.2 + 25.7 + 10.2 + 24.9 +

2: 9.4 + 24.1 + 8.6 + 23.3 +

3: 7.8 + 22.5 + 7 + 21.7 +

4: 6.2 + 20.9 + 5.4 + 20.1 + (2.7)

side = 251.7mm

total (x2) = 503mm

PARAMETERS of inductor traces:

- witdh = 0.3mm
- length = 503mm
- copper tickness = 18um (1/2 oz final copper thickness)

According to HERE, Rant = 1.66 ohms

So Then I have new input values, Lant = 1.68uH and Rant = 1.66 ohms to input on the ST25R95 calculator spreadsheet. Now I can easily recalculate the NFC circuit, I mean the caps and indutors of matching and filter circuits.

I wonder if I should consider the capacitance created between the traces of spposite sides, they are on exact same place, they just are in opposite board sides. PCB is 1.6mm FR4. dk (dielectric constant) can consider as 4.5.

Single side inductance
[image]

new inductor drawing.
[image]

Rant value
[image]

Coil "pins"
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Also I wonder if I do that (antenna drawn on both sides) if I could
>   reach more working distance (between the reader circuit and the tags)
>   than doing coil only on top side.*

and

> *If I need to continue the coil on bottom side also, do you have any
>   recommendation about how to draw a good PCB inductor?*

For near-field magnetic coupling it would be better if the coil was split between top and bottom copper layers with half the turns on the top layer and half on the bottom stacked above each other. That will allow you to use slightly fewer turns overall and get a slightly better coil Q factor. That will increase range slightly and, because coils are top and bottom you would get equal range performance from either side.

Designing coils to couple magnetism some distance requires the best amount of mutual coupling you can get between the windings of the transmit coil. Designs that are spiral are not the best but, given that you might have only one PCB layer to work with then it has to be a spiral but take note; the lower radius windings of the spiral are largely superfluous to the energy transmitted to the receiver and so, if you had (say) four layers, the optimum would be to put stacked turns on each of the four layers (just like a regular electromagnet).

So, I would look for a calculator that allows you to design the right inductance using 2 or more layers of the PCB.

Comment: Thanks. I could not find an online calculator for multilayer retangular planar inductors. Could you recommend me some one? or some software that can calculate this. My plan is to route the coil on top and bottom sides, PCB is 1.6mm thick, and make around 4 turns on each side. the maximum recommended inductance is 3uH for NFC coil.

Comment: I think there will be tools to do this but I can't recommend one off the top of my head. You could assume that a single layer 4 turn inductor of inductance "L" will become roughly "4L" when stacked above another layer of 4 turns. But, it will probably be more like 3.5L due to imperfect coupling.

Comment: I have also read in a webforum about that approximation that a double side coil inductance is around 4 times the value of a single side one. I have designed a new drawing of single side coil on ST's tool eDesignSuite with 4 turns (single side) and the the result that it is giving to me is 449.77nH. This value x4 equals 1.8uH. x3.5 equals to 1.57uH. Which of these values to you think is more suitable to use on the ST spreadsheet that calculate the filter and matching circuits? Maybe consider to multiply  by 3.75?

Comment: Somewhere between the two and it's really a guess. Inductor values are really hard to accurately calculate from physical layout.

Comment: I need a starting point. Then, 449.77nH (single side) x 3.75 = 1.68uH. I will consider this value as starting point... I will edit the topic soon with more information about the details of new drawing of antenna, now double sided.

Comment: I'm actually excited about this and look forward to what you reveal.

Comment: please check the edit1.

Comment: Yes, that looks good. I expect the capacitance will be more and a simple area and distance calculation would probably be enough to give you a number.

Comment: Consider that I calculated the new value of C23. Then if I calculate the capacitance of coil, then C23 would need to reduce its value? reduce from it the amount of coil capacitance?

Comment: I would also add a capacitor underneath C23 - you don't need to use it but, from experience you might require it. In the past (hand wound coils) I've made provision for three capacitors just so I can tweak things. Also, in your bottom diagram, what is all the flood of green about?

Comment: Thats a good idea, I will add another capacitor on bottom. The green flood is to prevent GND plane to exist in the coil area.